# i need a Substring to Extract Data from a field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a field that contains character in this format `1_US_01_103_157_G014`. The characters in the field are cojoined by `_` as you can see in the example given.

I would like to create a Tsql to extract each characters into its own column, for example provided Column 1 = 1_US_01_103_157_G014. Derived Column 2 = 1. Column 3 = US, column 4 = 01, column 5 = 103, column 6 = 157, column 7 = G014.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you already have a table with those 7 columns?

Comment: I already have a Column with tthe co-joined data.

Comment: what version of sql server are you on?

Comment: What do you mean that your "dev environment is very limited"?  All of the solutions given here are straight SQL Server code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy using CROSS APPLY. Note that the temp variable below enables you to test this. In your environment you would replace @tbl with whatever table you're working with.

```
-- Your table (change the query to point to your real table)
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT @tbl(col1) VALUES ('1_US_01_103_157_G014');

SELECT
  C1 = t.col1,
  C2 = SUBSTRING(t.col1,1,d1.D-1), 
  C3 = SUBSTRING(t.col1,d1.D+1,d2.D-d1.D-1),
  C4 = SUBSTRING(t.col1,d2.D+1,d3.D-d2.D-1),
  C5 = SUBSTRING(t.col1,d3.D+1,d4.D-d3.D-1),
  C6 = SUBSTRING(t.col1,d4.D+1,d5.D-d4.D-1),
  C7 = SUBSTRING(t.col1,d5.D+1,8000)
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',t.col1)))        AS d1(D)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',t.col1,d1.D+1))) AS d2(D)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',t.col1,d2.D+1))) AS d3(D)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',t.col1,d3.D+1))) AS d4(D)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('_',t.col1,d4.D+1))) AS d5(D);
```

**Returns**

```
C1                     C2  C3   C4   C5   C6    C7
---------------------- --- ---- ---- ---- ----- -------
1_US_01_103_157_G014   1   US   01   103  157   G014
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace underscores `_` and convert result to `xml` and then process it. Something like this.

```
declare @tbl table(col1 varchar(50))
insert @tbl(col1) values ('1_US_01_103_157_G014')

;with cte as(
    select col1, cast('<t><x>'+REPLACE(col1,'_','</x><x>')+'</x></t>' as xml) x
    from @tbl
)
select col1,
    t.v.value('x[1]', 'varchar(20)') col2,
    t.v.value('x[2]', 'varchar(20)') col3,
    t.v.value('x[3]', 'varchar(20)') col4,
    t.v.value('x[4]', 'varchar(20)') col5,
    t.v.value('x[5]', 'varchar(20)') col6,
    t.v.value('x[6]', 'varchar(20)') col7
from cte
cross apply x.nodes('t') t(v)
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, however my dev environment is very limited, i do not have the luxury of declaring etc. here is my mini solution i came up with for the first column LEFT(OrgUnit.XRefCode,1) and the last column RIGHT(OrgUnit.XRefCode,4). My issue is pulling those other characters between first column and last. is there no way we can do this using the charindex, or substring function ?

Comment: What do you mean you can't `DECLARE` @Olabode? Any user can declare a variable in SQL Server, even those with the public permission and nothing else. In this, however, Alex is using it to create sample data; which infers you don't understand the solution if you think it's part of it. If so, explain what you don't understand as it's up to you to support it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach I would suggest:

First, you will need a split function to convert a string into a table

```
go
create function [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String nvarchar(4000),
    @Delimiter nchar(1)
)
returns table
as
return
(
    with Split(stpos, endpos)
    as(
        select 0 as stpos, charindex(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        union all
        select endpos+1, charindex(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            from Split
            where endpos > 0
    )
    select 'Id' = row_number() over (order by (select 1)),
        'Data' = substring(@String,stpos,coalesce(nullif(endpos,0),len(@String)+1)-stpos)
    from Split
)
```

So now you can do this:

```
go
declare @inputString nvarchar(128) set @inputString = '1_US_01_103_157_G014'
select * from dbo.Split(@inputString, '_')
```

which produces a table:
[image]

Second thing ... You can use a [pivot operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) to convert row to columns

```
go
declare @inputString nvarchar(128) set @inputString = '1_US_01_103_157_G014'

SELECT 'values', [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]  
FROM  
(select Id, Data from dbo.Split(@inputString, '_')) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
max(Data)  
FOR Id IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

And `pivot` will produce the following result:

[image]

It's not quite clear from your question what exactly you are trying to do, but it is a good starting point.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, however my dev environment is very limited, i do not have the luxury of declaring etc. here is my mini solution i came up with for the first column LEFT(OrgUnit.XRefCode,1) and the last column RIGHT(OrgUnit.XRefCode,4). My issue is pulling those other characters between first column and last.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? If it is 2016 or higher you can use the STRING_SPLIT function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of creating your own and then proceed with the second part of Pavel's solution.